# Changing the properties of a dynamically created control

Tags: c#, controls

I have a Form with a `LayoutPanel` that has dynamically added `buttons` inside. The `buttons` are added at runtime, which works, but my problem is I'd like to set the properties to one of the `buttons` to disabled if a `textBox` is empty and enable it when it the `textBox` is not empty.

Here is a code example, with the error I am receiving below:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    // Create 3 buttons

    Button button1 = new Button();
    button1.Name = "button1";
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(button1, 0, 0);

    Button button2 = new Button();
    button1.Name = "button2";
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(button2, 0, 0);

    Button button3 = new Button();
    button3.Name = "button1";
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(button3, 0, 0);
}

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
    {
        button1.Enabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        button1.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

> CS0103 The name 'button1' does not exist in the current context

Should I be declaring the buttons elsewhere so the entire code can see that they do in fact exist or is my problem elsewhere? Thanks.

Comment: cant you do with javascript? $('#<%= myTextBox.ClientID %>')..on('input propertychange paste', function() {
    if ($this.val().length > 0) {
    $("#<%= button1.ClientID %>''").prop("disabled", false);
}else{ $("#<%= button1.ClientID %>''").prop("disabled", true); }
});

Comment: @user2744722 No, this question is about a C# Windows Forms application not ASP.net. javascript is not an option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must declare a Button outside `Form1_Load` if you want to access the button with name directly from other methods, because in your case the buttons are just available in the `Form1_Load` method :

```
Button button1;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Create 3 buttons
    button1 = new Button();
    button1.Name = "button1";
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(button1, 0, 0);
}

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Enabled = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text);
}
```

or if you want declare Buttons inside `Form1_Load`, you can access to Button like this :

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var btn = tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.OfType<Button>().Where(x => x.Name == "button1").FirstOrDefault();
    (btn as Button).Enabled = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text);
}
```

Comment: Thank you i'm glad to hear that.

Comment: I've to create customize exe for my windows app like I can add images, text, banner during installation and other options during uninstall... can you please suggest me any idea for this please?

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you could dynamically get the control from the Layout Panel and set the enabled property like this:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Control button = tableLayoutPanel1.Controls["button1"];

        button.Enabled = string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) ? false : true;
}
```

This approach is not as "safe" as declaring the buttons at form level, but I thought it would be useful to mention for times when you need to be genuinely dynamic in referencing controls.

Comment: This is useful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways you can do this, one would be to use the `Find` method of the TableLayoutPanel's Controls Collection like this.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn =(Button)tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Find("button1", true)[0];

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
    {
        btn.Enabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        btn.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

The second would be to use the buttons `Tag` Property to determine which control to use, I have used this in the past for dynamically generated controls.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Create 3 buttons
    Button button1 = new Button();
    button1.Name = "button1";
    button1.Tag = 1; //note the Tag property being used
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(button1, 0, 0);

    Button button2 = new Button();
    button1.Name = "button2";
    button2.Tag = 2;
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(button2, 0, 0);

    Button button3 = new Button();
    button3.Name = "button3";
    button3.Tag = 3;
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(button3, 0, 0);

}


private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control c in tableLayoutPanel1.Controls) //iterate through controls
    {
        if ((int)c.Tag == 1) //if Tag is equal then process
        {
            if (c is Button)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
                {
                    ((Button)c).Enabled = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    ((Button)c).Enabled = true;
                }
                break; //if you have multiple controls to process remove this
            }          //and assign the same tag to the controls you want processed
        }
    }
}
```